# Dynamically set initial state with aasm gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails-5, rails-activerecord, state-machine, aasm

I've an ActiveRecord model. I'd like to set an initial state depending on its attributes at the initialization. Here is my condition:

```
self.expected_delivery_date.blank? ? :in_preparation : :waiting
```

Is there a way to do that? Is it a bad idea?

Answer (score 4):

State [accepts](https://github.com/aasm/aasm/blob/35d6f6843f48760a1e719b507cc832f1a683127f/lib/aasm/instance_base.rb#L87-L96) a `Proc`, so yes, you can do this

```
initial_state lambda { |your_model|
    your_model.expected_delivery_date.blank? ? :in_preparation : :waiting
}
```

See more examples [here](https://github.com/aasm/aasm/blob/35d6f6843f48760a1e719b507cc832f1a683127f/spec/models/active_record/thief.rb).

Answer (score 2):

You could define an aasm hook method and set the state there:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  include AASM
  aasm do
    state :submitted, initial: true
    state :started
  end
  def aasm_ensure_initial_state
    self.aasm_state = :started
  end
end
```

That seems reasonable to me; you could give the most common initial state the `initial: true` option and then use logic in `aasm_ensure_initial_state` to set the less common initial state.

Comment: how would you use `aasm_ensure_initial_state` without using it in an `after_create`?